# Why does X === (A || B || C) not match anything?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array that looks like this:

```TypeScript
const subscriptions = [
    {
        "price": "20",
        "product": "apple",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "price": "10",
        "product": "orange",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "price": "10",
        "product": "orange",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "price": "10",
        "product": "orange",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
]
```

And I want to pull out all the array elements with a "product" of either `apple`, `banana`, or `pear`.

So I am using `filter()` like so:

```TypeScript
const currentPlans = subscriptions.filter(
  (subscription) =>
    subscription.product ===
    ('apple' || 'banana' || 'pear')
);
```

Since the array only has once instance of `apple` that should be what `currentPlans` contains.

But `currentPlans` is returning an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think `subscription.product === ('apple' || banana' || 'pear')` means? Is `'apple' === ('apple' || banana' || 'pear')` true?

Comment: `const currentPlans = subscriptions.filter(subscription => ["apple", "banana", "pear"].includes(subscription.product));`

Comment: The left & right side of the logical "or" (`||`) operator are treated as conditionals & evaluated as `truthy` or `falsy`. What you need is `subscription.product === 'apple' || subscription.product === 'banana' || subscription.product === 'pear'`. Or, I find it simpler to do: `['apple', 'banana', 'pear'].includes(subscription.product)`.

Comment: `(subscription) => ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'].includes(subscription.product)` ?

Comment: You have only a `typo`. Change it to that:  ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line not going to work as you expect. The right-hand side evaluates one value first(`apple`) and then checks equality. It never checks for `banana` or `pear`.

```
subscription.product === ("apple" || "banana" || "pear")
```

You should use another array to keep matches. Try like below.

##### Using indexOf

```js
const subscriptions = [ { price: "20", product: "apple", quantity: 1, }, { price: "10", product: "orange", quantity: 1, }, { price: "10", product: "orange", quantity: 1, }, { price: "10", product: "orange", quantity: 1, }, ];

const matches = ["apple", "banana", "pear"];

const currentPlans = subscriptions.filter(
  (subscription) => matches.indexOf(subscription.product) >= 0
);

console.log(currentPlans);
```

##### Using includes

```js
 const subscriptions = [ { price: "20", product: "apple", quantity: 1, }, { price: "10", product: "orange", quantity: 1, }, { price: "10", product: "orange", quantity: 1, }, { price: "10", product: "orange", quantity: 1, }, ];

const matches = ["apple", "banana", "pear"];

const currentPlans = subscriptions.filter(
  (subscription) => matches.includes(subscription.product)
);

console.log(currentPlans);
```

Comment: hi, which one is better in performance includes or indexOf

Comment: both should work, includes is clear in this case, as it outputs boolean directly

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Can you also add the includes version to your answer? For completeness.

Answer (score 0):

When you use conditional checks with respect to the equality check, as per the precedence level, the expression that is present on the right side of the equality check is evaluated first, so when you do `'apple'||'banana'||'pear'`, this statement alone evaluated and then checked against the expression on the left side.

So `'apple'||'banana'||'pear'` would evaluate to be truthy with the value `apple` and when you check this value against `subscription.product` the filter array would effectively return an object where the value of the property `product` is `apple`.

```js
const subscriptions = [
    {
        "price": "20",
        "product": "apple",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "price": "10",
        "product": "orange",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "price": "10",
        "product": "orange",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
    {
        "price": "10",
        "product": "orange",
        "quantity": 1,
    },
]
const currentPlans = subscriptions.filter(
  (subscription) =>
    subscription.product ===
    ('apple' || 'banana' || 'pear')
);

console.log(currentPlans)
```

Although this would work when filtering objects whose product's value is `apple` the logic is technically incorrect when you'd want to filter out values based on conditional checks. As mentioned above the conditional `OR` would always return the first value, i.e, `apple`, and check this value against each iterable value. In order to actually get this working with conditional checks, you'd have to individually check the value against every other value, like so:

```
const currentPlans = subscriptions.filter(
  (subscription) =>
    subscription.product === 'apple' || subscription.product === 'banana' || subscription.product === 'pear'
);
```

Or, an easier way to accomplish the same would be, by squashing all the values into an array and calling the `includes` method and passing the current iterable value as an argument.

```
const currentPlans = subscriptions.filter(
  (subscription) =>
    ['apple' || 'banana' || 'pear'].includes(subscription.product)
);
```